# chartjs creating data array dynamically

Tags: pie-chart, chart.js

Im creating a Pie chart using chartjs library, and Im wondering how I could represent the values the will be need to render the chart dynamically,

In chartjs.org tutorial the array of data is represented like this

```
var data = [
        {
           value: 300,
           color:"#F7464A",
           highlight: "#FF5A5E",
           labelColor : 'white',
           labelFontSize : '16'
        },
        {
            value: 100,
            color: "#46BFBD",
            highlight: "#5AD3D1",           
            labelColor : 'white',
            labelFontSize : '16'
        },
        {
            value: 100,
            color: "#FDB45C",
            highlight: "#FFC870",
            labelColor : 'white',
            labelFontSize : '16'
        }
    ]
```

and data will be pass as an argument to render the chart

```
new Chart(ctx).Pie(data);
```

this then renders a chart with 3 partitions:
[image]

But say I want to render X partitions, how can i make an array of data?

would I be able to do in a loop and append it to data?

Code so far:

```
function drawPie(ctx){

            var newopts = {
                inGraphDataShow: true,
                inGraphDataRadiusPosition: 2,
                inGraphDataFontColor: 'white',
            }

            //=========
            // this should be dynamic (data will come the parameter)
            //==========
            var data = [
            {
                value: 300,
                color:"#F7464A",
                highlight: "#FF5A5E",

                labelColor : 'white',
                 labelFontSize : '16'
            },
            {
                value: 100,
                color: "#46BFBD",
                highlight: "#5AD3D1",           

                labelColor : 'white',
                labelFontSize : '16'
            },
            {
                value: 100,
                color: "#FDB45C",
                highlight: "#FFC870",

                 labelColor : 'white',
                 labelFontSize : '16'
            }
        ]

        new Chart(ctx).Pie(data, newopts);

}
```

Comment: Hello i am stuck at same situation and i see the solution given but not able to understand the soltuion without the whole code and also the link given " Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/k4ztyqzc/ " is also not showing desired output.
Can i get whole source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to generate the data structure in the way Chart.js expects for a pie chart and if you don't know the maximum number of element generate the colors (if you know the maximum number of elements, you could just pick it from a color array). For instance

```
var dynamicData = [
    { label: "One", value: 23 },
    { label: "Two", value: 33 },
    { label: "Three", value: 43 },
    { label: "Four", value: 53 },
]

dynamicData.forEach(function (e, i) {
    e.color = "hsl(" + (i / dynamicData.length * 360) + ", 50%, 50%)";
    e.highlight = "hsl(" + (i / dynamicData.length * 360) + ", 50%, 70%)";
    // + any other code you need to make your element into a chart.js pie element
})

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(dynamicData);
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/k4ztyqzc/

Comment: thanks, works great.!! can u explain more has this lines works `e.color = "hsl(" + (i / dynamicData.length * 360) + ", 50%, 50%)";
    e.highlight = "hsl(" + (i / dynamicData.length * 360) + ", 50%, 70%)";` seems like the colors are not randomly generated.

Comment: Sure. What we are doing is picking the hue values off a 360 degree scale (so if there are 2 points we pick at 0 and 180, if there are 3 - 0, 120, 240...). HSL (Hue Saturation Luminosity) is an alternative to RGB values.

Comment: Hi, I am getting error `TypeError: (intermediate value).Pie is not a function`. I have tried to use it by: `var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {type: 'doughnut',data: dynamicData,});`. Now it is not reporting error but neither draw the graph, even if I will use `type: 'pie',`.

Comment: @ReddySK - you might want to set up a fiddle or post a new question (I would guess the javascript tag would be better from your error message). Cheers!

Comment: @potatopeelings I found the root cause. the problem was that I am using chartjs v2 which have changed the syntax.