# Chartjs charts drawing with the same colour after update

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Currently I am trying to programatically create multiple charts for a stock reporting website. I have a config which is defined as so..

```js
let chartConfig = {
        // The type of chart we want to create
        type: "line",
        // The data for our dataset
        data: {
            labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
            datasets: [{
                label: "Test",
                //default colour
                borderColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
                data: [],
                fill: false
            }]
        },
        // Configuration options go here
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            //Don't want to be able to remove the data.
            legend: {onClick: (e) => e.stopPropagation()}
        }
    };
```

I am then creating an array of charts that can then be updated later on.

```js
let chartArray = [];
let chartIds = [];
for(let context of document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")){
    let drawingContext = context.getContext("2d");
    let ticker = drawingContext.canvas.id;
    let localConfig = chartConfig;
    localConfig.data.datasets[0].borderColor = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';
    chartArray.push({ticker: ticker, chart: new Chart(drawingContext, localConfig)});
    chartIds.push(ticker);
}
```

Each chart should have a random colour associated with it, however the charts end up being the exact same colour.

Here is also the update code for the chart.

```js
socket.on("my_response", function(msg) {
    for(let packet of msg){
        addData(chartArray.find(chart => chart.ticker === packet.ticker).chart, packet.ticker, packet.data)
    }
});

function addData(chart, label, data) {
    console.log(chart);
    chart.data.datasets[0].label = label;
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data = data
    });
    chart.update();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use

```
let localConfig = chartConfig;
```

in javascript you do not get a copy of the object. Both values will point to the same reference. When you mutate one the original also mutates.

Try

```
let localConfig = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(chartConfig));
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object) for different possibilities to **deep clone** a javascript object.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create an array of colors dynamically. 
Check it [chartjs creating data array dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33204823/chartjs-creating-data-array-dynamically)